# Table with highlighted cells

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a blog using WordPress and I stumbled upon an error. My page displays the pages horizontally and the preview text is horrible. How do I fix this?
This is a fragment of my index.php :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <table class="centerTable">
            <tr>

                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

                    <th><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></th>

                    <th><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></th>

                <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is the style.css :

```
.centerTable {

margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
background-color: white;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
position: center;
width: 550px;
font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
}
.centerTable tr, th, td {
color: #444;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
transition: .4s background-color;}

.centerTable th, tr {
padding:3px 6px; font-weight:normal; 
color:#000;
}

.centerTable th:hover {
background-color: #ffa500;
color: white;
}
```

Could you please help me? I want my pages and the preview text to be one below another (like a table with 2 columns and numerous lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just give a max-width size to "table" and "tr" and work it as the CSS box model would do?